# Locate database must always be updated before search

Tags: bash, locate

I've noticed lately that when I run `locate [something]` it will always fail, even if I know the files are there (and I've seen them through a call to `locate` previously). I have to run `updatedb` before every time I want to locate something.

This seems to be a recent thing and hasn't been an issue in the past. It's hard to tell exactly when it's deleting the database but it might be across a reboot.

Is this normal/expected behavior or do I have something weird going on?

Expected:

```
sudo updatedb
locate file.c [success]
reboot #I think this is the trigger
locate file.c [success]
```

actual behavior:

```
sudo updatedb
locate file.c [success]
reboot #I think this is the trigger
locate file.c [fail]
sudo updatedb
locate file.c [success]
```

## Edits

This is Ubuntu 16.04 with 4.16.8 kernel.

`locate --version` returns `locate (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git`
`updatedb --version` also returns `4.7.0-git`

### However

apt show findutils disagrees on version (manually installed - I did install this but I didn't install any specific version)

```
Package: findutils
Version: 4.6.0+git+20160126-2
Priority: required
Essential: yes
Section: utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Andreas Metzler <ametzler@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 573 kB
Pre-Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
Suggests: mlocate | locate
Conflicts: debconf (<< 1.5.50)
Breaks: binstats (<< 1.08-8.1), debhelper (<< 9.20130504), guilt (<< 0.36-0.2), kernel-package (<< 13.000), libpython3.4-minimal (<< 3.4.4-2), libpython3.5-minimal (<< 3.5.1-3), lsat (<< 0.9.7.1-2.1), mc (<< 3:4.8.11-1), sendmail (<< 8.14.4-5), switchconf (<< 0.0.9-2.1)
Homepage: http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/findutils/
Task: minimal
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 280 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://repo.bblabs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Description: utilities for finding files--find, xargs
GNU findutils provides utilities to find files meeting specified criteria and perform various actions on the files which are found. This package contains 'find' and 'xargs'; however, 'locate' has been split off into a separate package.
```

Comment: Normally you would have your system init manager or cron run updatedb on a regular basis (on restart and every day or two) to update it. Sounds like that script may be malfunctioning. What distro are you running?

Comment: The newest version of findutils available from the canonical repo for that version of ubuntu is 4.6.0. Check `apt show findutils`. See if it's perhaps being pulled in from a third-party repo. That could be the problem.

Comment: Ok It looks like you manually installed findutils 4.7.0 somehow, but also had findutils 4.6.0 installed via apt already. That's a mess and is almost certainly contributing to your problem. So, you should be able to use apt to force-reinstall findutils. `apt-get --reinstall install findutils`. You may have to hunt down and manually delete/disable parts of the other installation of findutils. Another option would be to install mlocate. mlocate is what newer versions of Ubuntu use and it's a drop in replacement (same commands, mostly the same options).

Comment: Also, the source for findutils on your system is a third party repo... "bblabs"... whatever that is.  Just an fyi.

Comment: That's an internal repo - I know there's no issues there. I've moved over to mlocate and uninstalled `locate` and `updatedb`. However, apt is very concerned about me removing `findutils` as a whole - is this okay to do or do I need to have it around?

Comment: leave findutils, it includes other tools you need